# idivl of two numbers where the first is less than the second (in assembly)

Tags: assembly, x86, division

To my understanding, the idivl command in C assembly takes the 64-bit number represented by %edx (the more significant half) and %eax (the less significant), divides it by the argument, and stores the result in %edx:%eax again.

The behavior when a / b and a > b is as I would expect: 10 / 2 yields all 0's in %edx and 5 in %eax.

However, I'm not sure why a / b when b > a produces what it does. For example, when I switch those two to do 2 / 10 (that is, %edx is all 0's and and %eax is 2, and the 'argument' that's given to idivl is 10), the result is this:

%edx has 2; %eax has all 0's

Why is this the result? If we mash %edx and %eax together, that would mean 2 / 10 = 0000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000 in binary which is 2^33 in decimal, not anywhere near 2/10.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right that it divides EDX:EAX by its operand, but it doesn't store its result back there.
Instead, it puts the quotient in EAX and the remainder in EDX.